# Capture number and ignore a character

Tags: regex

I have a file with lines like:

```
528627266255,ANY VALUE,ANY VALUE,812323432-1
736353553,ANY OTHER VALUE,9123234321
```

I need to capture the number with 10 digits that begins with 8 or 9 and ignore the "-" character if is found.

I tried with '`[8-9]?[8-9]\d{8}-\d`' regular expression and works fine when the number has "-" but doesn't when this minus symbol is not included.

My question is, how i can capture the two cases with or without the minus character?

Comment: `[8-9]?[8-9]\d{8}-?\d`

Comment: If you need to capture 10 digits, then this `[8-9]?` is _not_ something you want to put inside a regex !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hM6aN3/1) showing multiple matches with the following regex against your test data:

```
[8-9]?[8-9]\d{8}-?\d
```

If you don't want the number at the beginning to also match, then

```
\b[8-9]?[8-9]\d{8}-?\d
```

[here](https://regex101.com/r/hM6aN3/2)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you say.

```
 # [89](?:-?\d){9}

 [89]                  # Starts with 8 or 9
 (?: -? \d ){9}        # Nine more digits, ignore minus sign
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex:

```
\b([8-9]{1}[0-9-]{9,10})\b
```

Comment: This `[0-9-]{9,10}` part of your regex will match `---------`.